# Mod rewrite does not work well in Mozilla

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am rewriting all `http://` and `http://www` on my website to `https://www`

Everything works well on all browser except on Mozilla Firefox. When i try to access my website using `http://example.com`, it redirects to: `https://www.example.com/https:/example.com/`

My .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(example\.com)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www)\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ hosted_form.php/?username=%1&hash=$1 [R,L]
```

Please how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your top 2 rules can be combined into one:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com$%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ hosted_form.php/?username=%1&hash=$1 [R,L,QSA]
```

Once that is done you need to clear your browser cache on Firefox since rewrite should behave same on all the browsers.

Comment: Though interesting this is not an answer at all. It should have been a comment.

Comment: Have you tried placing code as this big into comments on SO?